# Options to get data from web page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, parameters, querystringparameter

What to use and when (or: what you would choose and why):

1. default route and query string only
2. routing (changes only) without query string

Comment: If I got you right, first one I'd use for a single content pages which just are showing some info. The second one is more secure.

Comment: @LabLab thaks, but what is the actual different after all the params/action/controller is at uri in both of scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Clean Global.Asax - you dont need to treat every param, but to use patterns.
2. Security - for the simple users it will not intuitive to edit the param value in one mouse-click at the uri line.
3. You can simplify the site structure by using canonical form of URLs
4. You can hide the aspx extention, ‘?’ and ‘&’ characters in the query string
5. Helps you in SEO thru the refined site structure
6. Since the URL structure is simplified, the application is easily portable to a non ASP platform as the URLs don’t have aspx in them.