# Ajax error when there's a parameter in url

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a ajax code that fills a dropdownlist and I use mvc c#.
When  I call to my method from ajax and I have an url in the directions bar without parameters the code works correctly, but if I have a parameter in url in the directions bar  this not working and appears this error:
 "{readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}".

Here's my code:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"../Records/myList",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
   // data: JSON.stringify(Data),
    success: function (resul) {
        Function(resul);
    },
    error: function (message) {
    }
});
```

My url: http://localhost:123/Record/EditRecord ->> so it's works

My other url: http://localhost:123/Record/EditRecord/1 ->> It does not work like this

Thanks in advance.

Comment: both the url are same. what is the error you are getting

Comment: sorry, I already edited the second url. thanks.

Comment: `http://localhost:123/Record/EditRecord/1` => is this request goes to a GET method? I know ways to use various HTTP methods with `$.ajax` but I need to make sure what method you want to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From given second URL (which doesn't work) I assume that you want to use jQuery AJAX with `HttpGet` method. The URL pattern matches this route:

```
http://localhost:123/{controller}/{action}/{id}
```

which `id` treated as `UrlParameter`.

Hence you need to use action argument & data representing URL parameter values, like this example:

**Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult EditRecord(int id)
{
    // other stuff
}
```

**View (JS)**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Record/EditRecord",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json', // response type
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8', // header content type
    data: { id: 1 },
    processData: true, // this is important to use in GET methods
    success: function (result) {
        Function(result);
    },
    error: function (message) {
        // throw error
    }
});
```

Alternatively a direct usage of URL parameter is applicable for GET methods without specifying `data` content:

**View (JS)**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "Record/EditRecord/1",
    type: "GET",
    processData: true, // this is important to use in GET methods
    success: function (result) {
        Function(result);
    },
    error: function (message) {
        // throw error
    }
});
```

NB: Use [`jQuery.get`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) for simplified version:

```
$.get("/Record/EditRecord/1", function (result) {
          Function(result);
      }, "json").error(function (message) { // throw error 
      });
```

PS: This is an example for HTTP POST request if you're looking for proper POST method with AJAX.

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditRecord(Record rec)
{
    // other stuff
}
```

**View (JS)**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Record/EditRecord",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json', // response type
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', // header content type
    data: JSON.stringify({ rec: { id: 1, name: 'XXXX', ... }}),
    success: function (result) {
        Function(result);
    },
    error: function (message) {
        // throw error
    }
});
```

Reference:

[Do GET, POST, PUT, DELETE in ASP.NET MVC with jQuery AJAX](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/795483/Do-GET-POST-PUT-DELETE-in-asp-net-MVC-with-Jquery)

Answer (score 0):

i cant see any fault in the code but i suggest to try let the param come with it's name at server either if you choose to use data propery (of ajax function):

```
{key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2'}
```

or you use string query:

```
page?name=ferret&color=purple
```

bacuse you've just say that first method was work i assume there is no need to check POST/GET method.

EDIT:

be award to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45835759/options-to-get-data-from-web-page/45904936#45904936).